# Levenshtein distance on index elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Currently building a search engine with Node and Elasticsearch. I am trying to find a way to apply the Levenshtein distance to an index. For example, if I have an index of `javascript` and the search term entered contains `jvascrpt`, if I apply a Levenshtein distance of 2, it should only query that index.

If, *with the distance applied*, the query does not match then **all** indices should be queried. I know this is already possible with setting the index`property to`_all` or an empty string.

I am aware of the `fuzziness` property within a query but that is on the `body` of the document. Is there a way to apply this property to the index as well?

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search), the `index` property only accepts types of `String`, `String[]`, or `Boolean` so appreciate the query cannot bind to this property.

If Elasticsearch does not provide this functionality then I will find a way to implement it in JS. So, what I am asking is, is there any functionality that is provided by Elasticsearch that you can apply to a `query` property *(assumed)* where you can apply the Levenshtein distance *(i.e. via the `fuzziness` property)* to the `index`. Something like this maybe?:

```
query: {
    match: {
        index: {
            query: textToSearch,
            minimum_should_match: 1,
            fuzziness: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by adding an `index` property to the body of the document held. I could then query that field the usual way